# Catch a misconfigured link in .htaccess or in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Someone is linking to one of my websites like this:
`http://example.com/?p=contactus`
The `?p=contactus` is not supposed to be there.

How do I catch the `?p=contactus` in .htaccess and redirect it to http://example.com, or how do I catch it in php?

`$_REQUEST['p']` in php returns an empty string, and so does my usual `$_REQUEST['page']` (I use pretty URLs).

The link result in a fall back to my index.php since the `$_REQUEST['page']` returns an empty string; however, I would like to avoid Google thinking I have duplicate pages.

Comment: Do you already have rewrite rules in htaccess?  If your link is `/?p=contactus` then `$_REQUEST['p']` should not be empty unless you have something in the web server rewriting the URL.  Either way, a query string argument shouldn't naturally affect the page you're on.

Comment: I have these in .htaccess:

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !(\.(png|ico|css)|index\.php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php? [L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the redirection from Php. Use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to get the complete url . If it has a query string, then you can redirect the url to the url you want by sending the Location http header. It can be sent using the function header("Location: $redirect_url");

Comment: $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']  didn't work, probably because of my .htaccess file. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] works like a charm, it returns "/?p=contactus" which makes it easy to catch it and redirect with header("Location: http://example.com"); Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if this works

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=contactus
RewriteRule ^/ /?
```

I feel like I'm close, but Rewrites have never been my strong suite

Comment: This does not make any difference, I can still see the "?p=contactus" in the URL.

Comment: Sorry, still the same.